# Regex command not executing properly

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to take in a line from a text file and remove all punctuation, such as commas, periods, single quotes, double quotes, etc. and set the string to be lowercase. The code that I am using is:

```
inputLine.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]", "").toLowerCase();
```

Which to my understanding would do this, however it isn't. It also doesn't set words to lowercase either. So I included another line to specifically remove periods and commas:

```
inputLine.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

and then to split each word into a String array:

```
String[] strings = inputLine.split(" ");
```

However, I am still ending up with words such as `sets,` `There` `properties:[1]`. Does anyone know why this is happening, or could you provide a solution to this? I have not done much regex work before, so this is all very new to me.

Comment: Give us some samples of what an `inputLine` contains and what output you're getting.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: arshajii has pointed out what was wrong, I wasn't re-assigning the string when I was using .replaceAll(..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you reassigning `inputLine`? Remember: strings are immutable!

```
inputLine = inputLine.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]", "").toLowerCase();
```

By the way you can also use `.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "")` to replace all punctuation.

Comment: I definitely forgot to re-assign inputLine, thanks for pointing that out!